# C++ COM client calling Python COM server

Tags: python, c++, com, pythoncom

I have created a COM server in Python 2.7 (using pythoncom) and would like to call it from C++ code, but I do not know how.

The Python COM server:

`import pythoncom
class PyCOMTest:
    _public_methods_ = ['getNextNum']
    _reg_progid_ = "<some progid>"
    _reg_clsid_ = "{<some hash string>}"
    _reg_clsctx_ = pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
    numbb = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0
    def getNextNum(self):
        print "method called"
        PyCOMTest.numbb = PyCOMTest.numbb + 1
        return PyCOMTest.numbb
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Registering COM server..."
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PyCOMTest)`

I am able to call the COM server using clients written in Python and another in VBScript.

I know that C++ requires an interface that extends IUnknown to call CoCreateInstance and QueryInterface on, but I want the COM server to be entirely in Python.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it C or C++? C/C++ is not a language. You need to know what compiler you're using.

Comment: C++, sorry for the confusion. Also using VS2010, so I don't have the latest and greatest C++ features.